# Bootstrap Collapse a List to Select Dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

using Bootstrap, I have an unordered list that I want to collapse into a select/option dropdown for size xs, I am currently doing it by having 2 divs, one that is hidden for sm, md and lg and the other hidden for xs.

Although this works there is always redundant code not being displayed, could it be improved?

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
<ul id="myList">
<li><a href="http://someurl1">url 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://someurl2">url 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://someurl3">url 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
<select name="mySelect" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="http://someurl1">url 1</option>
<option value="http://someurl2">url 2</option>
<option value="http://someurl3">url 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg` is equivilent to `visible-xs`

Larger screen sizes also inherit column widths from lower screen sizes, so `col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3` only needs to be `col-sm-3`

Aside from that you might try something like keeping the ul for mobile, putting a mobile only element infront of it, and wrapping it in a `position: relative` div, and then using hover & focus to show/hide the nav menu. So, HTML like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="visible-xs mobile-tab">Nav</div>
        <ul id="myList">
            <li><a href="http://someurl1">url 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://someurl2">url 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://someurl3">url 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

With CSS like this:

```
.nav-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav-wrapper .mobile-tab {
        height: 15px;
        line-height: 15px;
        background-color: #c0c0c0;
    }

    #myList {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 0;
    }

    .nav-wrapper .mobile-tab:hover + #myList,
    .nav-wrapper .mobile-tab:focus + #myList {
        display: block;
    }
}
```